# How to make edit form with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have HTML code:

```html
<ul class="nav-cats">
      <li><a>Транспор</a> 
        <span style="float :right; opacity: .6" class="edit-section hide-btn">
           <span style="margin-right: 10px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil edit"></span>
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete"></span>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li><a>Продукты</a>
        <span style="float :right; opacity: .6" class="edit-section hide-btn">
           <span style="margin-right: 10px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil edit"></span>
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete"></span>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li><a>Работа</a>
        <span style="float :right; opacity: .6" class="edit-section hide-btn">
           <span style="margin-right: 10px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil edit"></span>
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete"></span>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li><a>Услуги</a>
        <span style="float :right; opacity: .6" class="edit-section hide-btn">
           <span style="margin-right: 10px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil edit"></span>
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete"></span>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li><a>Напитки</a>
        <span style="float :right; opacity: .6" class="edit-section hide-btn">
           <span style="margin-right: 10px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil edit"></span>
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete"></span>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li><a>Еда вне дома</a>
        <span style="float :right; opacity: .6" class="edit-section hide-btn">
           <span style="margin-right: 10px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil edit"></span>
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete"></span>
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="add-new-cat button-edit">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
```

> Above code was compiled with jade

When I'll click on "*Anchor*" my *JavaScript* file will save *this.innerText* in to *localStorage*.
Ok, that's not a problem.

But I need that, when I click on

```html
<span style="margin-right: 10px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil edit">
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var listCatsA = $('.nav-cats>li>a');

  var buttonEdit = $('.button-edit');
  var editSection = $('.edit-section');


  editSection.hide();

  listCatsA.on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    localStorage.userCati = $(this)[0].innerText;
  });

  var editTextCat = $('.edit');

    editTextCat.on('click', function(){
      
    });


  buttonEdit.click(function(){

   if(editSection.hasClass('hide-btn')){
      editSection.removeClass('hide-btn');
      editSection.fadeIn();
   }
   else{
    editSection.addClass('hide-btn');
    if(editSection.hasClass('hide-btn')){
      editSection.fadeOut();
    }
   }
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

"Anchor" must become as  with value from active "li>a"
How I'll finish my value correction, when I push enter value must become default.

> HTML included "bootstrap" "jquery"

Whether do that with JavaScript + PHP?

Comment: where is your javascript and what are you asking?

Comment: you probably need to provide full js code

Comment: I'm added javascript.